# Org mode icalendar export: how to avoid timestamp in description or summary

Tags: emacs, export, org-mode, icalendar

I have an agenda that I want to export as an icalendar file.

I do not use properties and org-mode export determines summary and description automatically from the headers and bodys.

The entries were like this one

```
* <2015-05-19 Tue 13:45-15:15> My entry
```

Sometimes, this worked properly. I got an entry with summary "My entry" at the time specified by the timestamp. Now, the entry is correctly put at the time, but the timestamp is included into the summary and therefore I can see it in my calendar application.

I have tried, permuting the order of timestamp and header, but the best i have got is by putting the timestamp in the body, as in the following entry

```
* My entry
  <2015-05-19 Tue 13:45-15:15>
```

Now, the tismestamp is no longer in the summary, but in the description of the event.

I have tried going through the org-mode options but I have not find any possible explanation of this changing.

Can anybody help me in using timestamp to correctly put the event, but avoiding to include it into the exported event?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem.  I found that you can add properties to each item to specify what should be in the summary, like so:

```
* <2015-05-19 Tue 13:45-15:15> My entry
  :PROPERTIES:
  :SUMMARY: My entry
  :END:
```

(You can also add LOCATION and DESCRIPTION properties)

But that's pretty annoying.